# unable to truncate a table using remote login

Tags: mysql, bash

I use remote login to connect to the database (residing on AWS). I'd like to truncate one of my tables. But this command does not seem to work on bash:

```
mysql --login-path=remote --database=marketing  'truncate table my_test_table'
```

I get the message

> ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'mdb_updater'@'%' to
>   database 'truncate table pedram_test_table'

`mdb_updater` is my username on the database.

This is when I can successfully run `mysqlimport` and `mysqldump` using the same credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL cli treats positional argument as database name, pass statement you want to run with `--execute` option:

```
mysql --login-path=remote --database=marketing --execute 'truncate table my_test_table'
```